# Sql connection error in visual stuio C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net

I am new to visual studio and trying to connect to a database "demoDB" and update the table "Table1" which has two columns UID and Name. Below is my code.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=./SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=DemoDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table1 values ('WCGC1212','Watson')", con);
int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
con.Close();
```

When i debug it i am getting below error

---

Index #0

Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

LineNumber: 0

Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider

Procedure:

---

Can you please let me know how to fix this error..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: `Data Source=.\SqlExpress` instead of `Data Source=./SqlExpress`

Comment: @Coolenough There is a holo tickbox next to each answer... marking correct answers saves other people from troubleshooting your issue when it is solved and also gives you a couple of points.